# The cohomology of meromorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, sheaf-theory, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

Let $A$ be a sheaf such that $$A(U) = \{ f \in \mathbb M(U): f \in \mathbb{O}(U \backslash\{p_1,\ldots, p_n\}) \ \mbox{with at worst a simple pole at}\ p_i  \}. $$, where $\mathbb M(U)$ means the set of meromorphic functions on $U$ and $\mathbb O(U)$ means the set of holomorphic functions on $U$. What is the cohomology of $A$ on the Riemann sphere?

Comment: Have you tried applying Riemann-Roch theorem?

Comment: @Mihail Actually I haven't learned that and I believe I can calculate directly by using C* and C\{0} to cover the Riemann sphere, but I have difficulties whne dealing with poles.

Comment: Can you use short exact sequences of sheaves?